# How to set history length for msys?

Tags: command-line, msysgit, command-history, msys

On my Debian VM I'm setting the `$HISTSIZE` and `$HISTFILESIZE` (and other history related environment variables) on system start / profile load:

`~/.profile`

```
export HISTSIZE=100000
export HISTFILESIZE=100000
```

I can access these vars in [msys](http://msysgit.github.com/):

```
user@machine /usr
$ echo $HISTFILE
/c/Users/user/.bash_history

user@machine /usr
$ echo $HISTSIZE
500

user@machine /usr
$ echo $HISTFILESIZE
500
```

How can I set them permanently?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash would ignore `~/.profile` if `~/.bash_profile` exists. So you need to check if `.bash_profile` is there. And to be safe, you better configure all these settings in `.bashrc` and `source` it in `.profile`. For example:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return0
source ~/.bashrc
$ cat ~/.bashrc
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return 0
export HISTSIZE=100000
export HISTFILESIZE=100000
$
```

Comment: From bash's manual: When  bash is invoked as an **interactive login shell**, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes  commands  from  the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.  After reading
       that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`,
       in  that order, and reads and executes commands from the **first one** that
       exists and is readable.  ... ...

When an **interactive shell that is not a login shell**  is  started,  bash
       reads  and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what you are describing is the Linux Bash. It works fine. What doesn't work is to set the `HIST*` options for my msys command line on Windows. It only has a `.bash_history` file in the user home folder `~/` -- no `.profile` and no `.bash_profile`.

Comment: A added the files `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` with the code from your post to my home directory and it works! Thank you!